# ng-repeat using scope function return value not calling function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having a bit of a trouble using the return value of a function as the array to iterate over in ng-repeat in a custom directive.

The code is rather simple:

```
.directive('treeRow', [function () {
    return function createDirective() {
        var treeController;
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            require: '^treeGrid',
            scope: {
                row: '='
            },
            templateUrl: 'components/treegrid/templates/row.html',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, gridController) {
                treeController = gridController;
            },
            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.getColumnDefinitions = function () {
                    return treeController.getColumnDefinitions();
                };
            }
        };
    }();
}]);
```

The template:

```
<tr>
    <td ng-repeat="column in getColumnDefinitions()">{{row[column.key]}}</td>
</tr>
```

Using a debugger, the `getColumnDefinitions` function is actually never called in the template. Inspecting the code, the function is present though.

Simply echoing it in the template works fine though:

```
<tr>
    <td>{{getColumnDefinitions()}}</td>
</tr>
```

Using ng-init to assign the return value to a temporary variable doesn't call the function either.

Adding the data directly to the scope doesn't work either:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, gridController) {
    treeController = gridController;
    scope.columnDefinitions = gridController.getColumnDefinitions();
},
```

This directive is part of another ng-repeat, used as:

```
<tree-row ng-repeat="row in data" row="row"></tree-row>
```

**Update**

Apparently this is an issue with the `td` element. Changing it to be a `div` element instead works just fine:

```
<tr>
    <div ng-repeat="column in getColumnDefinitions()">{{ row[column.key] }}</div>
</tr>
```

Using angular.js 1.3.* .

Any suggestions / hints are welcome,
Thanks :)

Comment: Did you try using `require: true` for your directives? Or did you did you want the `<tree-row>` and `<tree-grid>` elements to be there?

Comment: `replace: true`. That's what @Ian means, but it's now [deprecated](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/eec6394a342fb92fba5270eee11c83f1d895e9fb), sadly (and IMHO, astonishingly).

Comment: @Blackhole Jeez, I'm crazy. I'm not sure why I typed `require`. I can't believe it's deprecated, I didn't know that!